# INSERT if not Exist Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
id     follow_id    follower_id
 1  |       2     |      3
 2  |       2     |      4
 3  |       2     |      5
 4  |       2     |      6
 5  |       3     |      7
 6  |       3     |      8
```

I'd like to skip If i try to insert the "couple" follow_id 2, follower_id 3 without do subquery for the performance

can I do INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or something of this?

**UPDATE, for symfony user**

after answers. i Use Symfony, and for do

```
UNIQUE INDEX followee_and_follower (follow_id,follower);
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official syntax for this is

```
INSERT IGNORE ...
```

However, in your case it may actually be preferable to do

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id
```

See [benchmarks](http://www.eddieoneverything.com/programming/mysql-performance-tip-on-duplicate-key-is-faster-than-insert-ignore-but-failing-with-a-duplicate-key-error-is-a-lot-faster.php). In my experience, this hack only improves performance if you've got a primary key--the optimizer won't recognize the no-op if you do `follower_id = follower_id`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the syntax you want is `INSERT IGNORE`.

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error occurs. Ignored
>   errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do
>   not.

This requires a unique index on (follow_id,follower_id) so you will need to add that if it does not exist already:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX followee_and_follower (follow_id,follower);
```

Comment: i try to INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable (follow_id, follower_id) VALUES (2,3), but add a row with new id and follow_id 2 follower_id 3

Comment: You need a unique index on (follow_id,follower_id). Please see my updated answer above.